# IPTables scenario explanation (How does my log rules are being hit?)

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables, openwrt

I have the iptables rules bellow from my OpenWRT router, I can not understand the scenario, in which my two logging rules are being hit (inside `zone_wan_dest_REJECT` and `zone_wan_src_REJECT`), because -for example-:

in `forwarding_wan_rule`, all packets will be accepted by `zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT` before entring `zone_wan_dest_REJECT`. But in practice both logging are really executed but I cannot understand how, could any body explain that for me please?

And could some one also please explain how do these rules identifies my wan_dest from lan_dest? In other word how they know the packets going to my lan and the packets going to wan? I cannot understand that here as well.

```
root@rt01:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
input_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for input */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* !fw3 */
syn_flood  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN /* !fw3 */
zone_lan_input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
zone_wan_input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
zone_wan_input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
forwarding_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for forwarding */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* !fw3 */
zone_lan_forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
zone_wan_forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
zone_wan_forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
output_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for output */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* !fw3 */
zone_lan_output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
zone_wan_output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
zone_wan_output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain forwarding_lan_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain forwarding_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain forwarding_wan_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain input_lan_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain input_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain input_wan_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain output_lan_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain output_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain output_wan_rule (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain reject (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */ reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain syn_flood (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 25/sec burst 50 /* !fw3 */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
forwarding_lan_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for forwarding */
zone_wan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: forwarding lan -> wan */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port forwards */
zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
input_lan_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for input */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port redirections */
zone_lan_src_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
output_lan_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for output */
zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_src_ACCEPT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_dest_ACCEPT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_dest_REJECT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 /* !fw3 */ LOG level warning prefix "REJECT(dest wan)"
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_forward (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
forwarding_wan_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for forwarding */
zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  esp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: @rule[7] */
zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:isakmp /* !fw3: @rule[8] */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port forwards */
zone_wan_dest_REJECT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_input (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
input_wan_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for input */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc /* !fw3: Allow-DHCP-Renew */
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request /* !fw3: Allow-Ping */
ACCEPT     igmp --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: Allow-IGMP */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port redirections */
zone_wan_src_REJECT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_output (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
output_wan_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for output */
zone_wan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_src_REJECT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 /* !fw3 */ LOG level warning prefix "REJECT(src wan)"
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
reject     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
root@rt01:~#
```

#### Edited: added iptables -L -v (according to request)

```
root@rt01:~#  iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   88  9788 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
 1870  857K input_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for input */
 1232  798K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* !fw3 */
   61  3016 syn_flood  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN /* !fw3 */
  492 34287 zone_lan_input  all  --  br-lan any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
   82  4472 zone_wan_input  all  --  pppoe-wan any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
   64 20992 zone_wan_input  all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2213 LOG level warning prefix "(mycustom_ssh_forward) "
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh LOG level warning prefix "(ssh_forward) "
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
40262   11M forwarding_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for forwarding */
38858   11M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* !fw3 */
 1403  208K zone_lan_forward  all  --  br-lan any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
    1    56 zone_wan_forward  all  --  pppoe-wan any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_wan_forward  all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
    2    92 reject     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 120 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   88  9788 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
 1865  251K output_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for output */
  975  191K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* !fw3 */
   23  3055 zone_lan_output  all  --  any    br-lan  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
  867 57072 zone_wan_output  all  --  any    pppoe-wan  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_wan_output  all  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain forwarding_lan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain forwarding_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain forwarding_wan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input_lan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input_wan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain output_lan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain output_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain output_wan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain reject (5 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   61  2968 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */ reject-with tcp-reset
   87 22588 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain syn_flood (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   61  3016 RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 25/sec burst 50 /* !fw3 */
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   21  2975 ACCEPT     all  --  any    br-lan  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1403  208K forwarding_lan_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for forwarding */
 1403  208K zone_wan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: forwarding lan -> wan */
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port forwards */
    2    92 zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  492 34287 input_lan_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for input */
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port redirections */
  492 34287 zone_lan_src_ACCEPT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   23  3055 output_lan_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for output */
   23  3055 zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_src_ACCEPT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  492 34287 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_dest_ACCEPT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2267  265K ACCEPT     all  --  any    pppoe-wan  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_dest_REJECT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 reject     all  --  any    pppoe-wan  anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
    0     0 reject     all  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_forward (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    56 forwarding_wan_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for forwarding */
    0     0 zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  esp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: @rule[7] */
    0     0 zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:isakmp /* !fw3: @rule[8] */
    1    56 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port forwards */
    0     0 zone_wan_dest_REJECT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_input (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  146 25464 input_wan_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for input */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc /* !fw3: Allow-DHCP-Renew */
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request /* !fw3: Allow-Ping */
    0     0 ACCEPT     igmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: Allow-IGMP */
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate DNAT /* !fw3: Accept port redirections */
  146 25464 zone_wan_src_REJECT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_output (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  867 57072 output_wan_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3: user chain for output */
  867 57072 zone_wan_dest_ACCEPT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_src_REJECT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   82  4472 reject     all  --  pppoe-wan any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
   64 20992 reject     all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere             /* !fw3 */
root@rt01:~#
```

Comment: Try adding these rules:
iptables -A zone_wan_dest_REJECT -j DROP
iptables -A zone_wan_src_REJECT -j DROP

Comment: Could you run iptables -L -v and post the output?

Comment: @cybernard I don't understand why is that?

Comment: @user2313067 I did that and edited the question.

Comment: If a packet, for any reason, reaches the end of a chain, it will return to its parent for further processing.

Comment: how do these rules identifies my wan_dest from lan_dest? If you look at the last 3 rules of INPUT it forward traffic based on the ethernet adapter.  The br-lan adapter is the lan.  All traffic from ppoe-wan, and eth1 are sent to zone_wan.  If we looked at iptables-save, it would say iptables -A INPUT -o br-lan -j zone_lan_input   The **-j** command causes all matching traffic to jump to whatever chain.

Comment: It makes more sense with `-v`, but the first part (how log is being hit is still not very clear).

Comment: https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html   Chapter 6 of this document has specific information.  The document covers iptables in great detail.